# How to stop horizontal stretching particular column row in table layout?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

As i am trying to use table layout in android page using stretch column property for table layout
here is code

```
 <TableLayout
        style="@style/TableLayoutStyle"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
         ><------- Column property for column 2nd only  

        <!-- Lable Area -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwSpnLbl"
            style="@style/TableRowStyle" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblCust"
                style="@style/LabelStyle"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:text="@string/lblCust" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnCust"
                style="@style/SpinnerStyle"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:hint="@string/SelectCust" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- Spinner Area -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwSpn"
            style="@style/TableRowStyle" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblPros"
                style="@style/LabelStyle"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:text="@string/lblPros" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnPospect"
                style="@style/SpinnerStyle"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:hint="@string/SelectProspect" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- Text Area -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwEditTxt"
            style="@style/TableRowStyle" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblCommo"
                style="@style/LabelStyle"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:text="@string/lblCommo" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnComodity"
                style="@style/SpinnerStyle"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- Button Submit Section -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwOESubmit"
            style="@style/TableRowStyle"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <!-- Lable Area -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblCust1"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:text="@string/strNull" />

            <TableLayout
                style="@style/TableLayoutStyle"
                android:background="@drawable/border" >

                <!-- Lable Area -->

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tblRwSpnLbl1"
                    style="@style/TableRowStyle"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="left" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
                        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                        android:text="@string/edit" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                        android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                        android:text="@string/cancel" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwOESubmit1"
            style="@style/TableRowStyle"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEdit1"
                style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:text="@string/edit" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel1"
                style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                android:text="@string/cancel" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

the last row is of buttons Edit & cancel want to show them at center of tht particular row but it shows me in stretched row in image (2) so want to stop stretching for that particular Row of buttuons
such as shown in below image (3) how to achieve that as i tried hard to get them done but still not at the center (1)

[image]

```
  <style name="ButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">85dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">35dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/press_btn_effct</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can you show your "ButtonStyle".

Comment: see above i edited post

Comment: I think you should wrap the two button in one `LinearLayout` and add one view with column 1 and the linearlayout in column 2. The view will contain nothing but it will take the space of column 1.

Comment: @AditiK posted an answer. Use `android:layout_column` attribute you can wrap button in LinearLayout and place that in 2nd column. just try the answer i have posted. Any query you can left a comment.

Comment: thnks user3110424 but its showing me below the spinner Level i want it to be exact center of that particular row ..so tht buttons will not look at one side of row

Comment: is thr any way to stop stretching for particular row so tht will make it to center align?

Comment: @AditiK sorry didn't get you. Do you want your button in the center of the screen? As i have understood your requirements seeing your demo pic. You like put the button as in 3. Which align the button in 2nd column.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45524/discussion-between-user3110424-and-aditi-k)

Answer (score 1):

here i got solution for center button

```
 <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRwOESubmit"
            style="@style/TableRowStyle"
            android:background="#bcbcbc"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_span="2"<-----used it with linear layout
                android:gravity="center" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                    android:text="@string/submit" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                    android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
                    android:text="@string/cancel" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_column` Attribute in your layout something like this. 
**EDIT**
Feel free to change it as your requirement is.

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tblRwOESubmit1"
        style="@style/TableRowStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_column="1" // For placing button in 2nd column
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEdit1"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"

            android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
            android:text="@string/edit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel1"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:fontFamily="verdana,arial,helvetica"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />
       </<LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: @AditiK posted as suggested you in the comments. Check it once. any query, then let me know